# MailChimp connects through live site, but not through dev site

Tags: 6, emails

This is using the latest MailChimp Drupal 6 version 6.x-2.6

On the Live site MailChimp connects correctly and gives me the lists on my client's account.

But on my Dev site (WAMP server) it fails to connect and claims I have no valid lists. This is an issue because I need to do some custom blocks to link through to MailChimp and obviously I can't do that on the Live site.

Any ideas as to what might cause this effect?

Comment: I could think of a few, firstly, did you put your WAMP server "online"? Click the WAMP icon and see if it says "Put offline" then yours is online at the moment. Secondly it could be a firewall issue. Try disabling any firewalls, virus scanners. It doesn't really seem to be related to drupal though ...

Comment: WAMP is online. Probably not virus scanner (I wasn't actually using one on this machine when I first tried this). Firewall seems unlikely (I've been using this machine for all sorts of connections from WAMP for other clients) but I'll check it out.